# Issue of running sql query from php code

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, field

I have written this code to create a search form and get results from mysql table:

```
<?
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_database = 'jatc_university_j32';

// Database Connection String
$con = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Search: <input type="text" name="FieldValue" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <?
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['FieldValue'])) {

            $FieldValue = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['FieldValue']);

            $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Fieldvalue from #__rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName = 'candidatname'");

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my database table I have FieldName: candidatname, candidatsurname and FieldValue: John, Wayne etc.
I want to search entering a name and return the other details for this candidate
Anyway when I run code nothing happens
Can you please check if I am doing wrong something because I get the same result in a lot of trials

Comment: Where does your code stop running after clicking the submit button?

Comment: Enable php errors, and display errors at the top of the script. Also check for any mysql errors. The mysql_* functions are now depreciated. You should really be using PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: If you are trying to search after you press Submit button then you need to check if(isset($_POST['submit']) before continuing

Comment: When editting your question, I noticed that you didn't close the if statement: `if(!empty($_REQUEST['FieldValue']))`. Sometimes these kind of things also cause problems. Please check your code and see if it happens again with the new code!

Comment: Do you have short tags `<?` turned on? Try using `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Nothing happens beacuse you are using `<? ?>` for php, but you should use `<?php  ?>`
2.Your form method is `post` then you should check variblae like this on form submit: 
`if (!isset($_POST['FieldValue']))` 
3. `"SELECT Fieldvalue from #__rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName = 'candidatname'"` 
instead of candidatename, give the value that you got from the form:

```
"SELECT Fieldvalue from #__rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName = '".$FieldValue."'" <BR>
```

4. `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` add a name property to this like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit"/>
```

and it will work, i tested after applying these changes!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?php

$formpartone = <<<EODformpartone
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="get">
            Search: <input type="text" name="FieldValue" value=""/><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
EODformpartone;

$formparttwo = <<<EODformparttwo
    </body>
</html>
EODformparttwo;


if (!isset($_GET["FieldValue"]))
{    
echo $formpartone;
echo $formparttwo;
}

ELSE {
function search_candidate(){
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "jatc_university_j32";

$searchstring =  $_GET["FieldValue"];


$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

IF(!$link){
    echo ('unable to connect to database');
}

ELSE {

                $query = "SELECT candidatename, candidatesurname

FROM (
SELECT c.SubmissionID,

max(CASE WHEN c.FieldName='candidatename' THEN c.Fieldvalue ELSE 0 END) AS 'candidatename',
max(CASE WHEN c.FieldName='candidatesurname' THEN c.Fieldvalue ELSE 0 END) AS 'candidatesurname'

FROM mf2sn_rsform_submission_values as c


GROUP BY c.SubmissionID
) a
WHERE a.candidatename LIKE '".$searchstring."' OR a.candidatesurname LIKE '".$searchstring."'"; 


            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

                    echo "<table>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){    
                    echo  "<tr><td>".$row['candidatename']."</td><td>".$row['candidatesurname']."</td></tr>";


            } echo  "</table>";
}
mysqli_close($link);


}

echo $formpartone;
echo search_candidate();
echo $formparttwo;

}


?>
```

Sample table mysql

```
CREATE TABLE candidates 
    (
 id int auto_increment primary key, 
 SubmissionID int,
 FieldName varchar(20), 
 Fieldvalue varchar(30)
 );

INSERT INTO candidates
(SubmissionID, FieldName, Fieldvalue)
VALUES
(1,'candidatename','Bob'),
(1,'candidatesurname', 'Smith'),
(2,'candidatename','Jack'),
(2,'candidatesurname', 'Doe');
```

[SQLFiddle demo of the sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b4b/6)

You should look into the validation and sanitation of the search string to avoid SQL injection. And what to do when no candidates are found with the name you inserted. However, I think for now it is important to test if everything works.

Comment: _Actually I want results of query to be printed as table under the form. Is this possible? When I try the code I take Article not found 404 Error_

Comment: @user1997567 404 means a page not found. So, my guess would be you have not tried the two pages I suggested. Before we continue try out the two pages. This will test if you the mysql query is correct and the the script works until this point.

Comment: I am not really sure what to change in code. Tried to replace just POST with PHP_SELF unsuccessfully

Comment: @user1997567 best not to change anything before you get the basics to work.

Comment: Yes but still problem remains. Please help

Comment: No I still dont know how to modify code you kindly provided to have both form and result table in the same page

Comment: @user1997567 look at my new edited version, in this version I have included everything in one page.

Comment: Gives no result and Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jatc_university_j32\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(77) : eval()'d code on line 51

Comment: I am using $query = 'SELECT candidatname, candidatsurname FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE candidatname LIKE"'.$searchstring.'" OR candidatsurname LIKE "'.$searchstring.'"'; where candidatname and candidatsurname are FieldNames in table rsform and what we look for are FieldValues

Comment: @user1997567 then the problem will be with the search query. Try this: $query = "SELECT * FROM  \`#__rsform_submission_values\`";. This is to test if you get any results.

Comment: I changed they query in your code as you asked but still getting same warning with no results. I tried this query separately {artsqltable query="SELECT Fieldvalue from #__rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName = 'candidatname' " headerNames="Name"} {/artsqltable} everything ok

Comment: Can it be that joomla has a different way of connection with database rather $db = JFactory::getDbo(); ????

Comment: Joomla could be an complicating factor. For now focus on getting a query from the database. B.T.W. if you using Joomla why not install a plugin / component that will do a search?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin when I run your query I get  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query = "SELECT * FROM '#__rsform_submission_values'"' at line 1

Comment: Only run `SELECT * FROM '#__rsform_submission_values;` $query is part of PHP.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `mf2sn_rsform_submission_values`
LIMIT 0 , 30 goes OK

Comment: Do you see that you keep changing the table and column names? That complicates the matter. Run `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mf2sn_rsform_submission_values;`

Comment: Sorry my fault. The problem is that I am using ArtData extension in Joomla to create some reports and their query accept table only without extension mf2sn.

Comment: Is there any way I send you a screenshot of table taken from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Use this `show create table mf2sn_rsform_submission_values;` and copy it in www.sqlfiddle.com and place it in a comment below. It will give the total data structure of you table without data. At this moment you don't have enough reputation point to upload a picture.

Comment: You need to do this in phpMyAdmin or direct on the command line from mysql. Same place as the other Mysql queries you did before.

Comment: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

Comment: RSForm!Pro saves data in a very strange table thats why I have to send you an image

Comment: I am in XAMPP Joomla using extension RSForm!Pro for entering data.

Comment: I run the query show create table mf2sn_rsform_submission_values; in PhPMyAdmin and I got the message: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available because of non regular RSForm tables

Comment: Go to myPHPAdmin run select the database. Then go to the SQL tab and type in `SHOW TABLES;` To determine the table you want where the data is in. Then run `SHOW CREATE TABLE mf2sn_rsform_submission_values;`. Or replace `mf2sn_rsform_submission_values` with the name of the table with the correct data.

Comment: Query executed -columns SubmissionValueID, FormID, SubmissionID, FieldName, Fieldvalue.

Comment: FieldName contains the fields I created inside the form like candidatename etc FieldValues contains values like John etc. Problem of RSForm is that all FieldValues are one column and datas for a person differs from data of another person by SubmissionID like 1 for the first person, 2 for the second

Comment: Is the data name form the candidate and the surname from the candidate in table `mf2sn_rsform_submission_values`. Like so `FieldName = candidatename; Fieldvalue = Bob; FieldName = Candidatesurname = Smith; FieldName = candidatename; Fieldvalue = "Jack"; FieldName = candidatesurname; Fieldvalue = Doe`;

Comment: Exactly so is the situation of the table

Comment: Great that complicates the matter even more. I working on a solution. Have a look at this SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05b4b/6.

Comment: In your opinion should I give up RSForms which create such a terrible situation? Can you advice me some extension more specific for this search and report thing in Joomla???

Comment: Yes, to be honest. I think there a better ways of creating a form. And you have already proven that you are able to created a form, that is the form you use to search the database. Furthermore, there are also possibilities of other form creators in Joomla.

Comment: Yes but I need something that also enters data in regular tables and not like this RSForm.

Comment: @user1997567 check my edit. Is the candidate data the only data you need to store in a database?

Comment: Yes for now because I havent made it work yet on my web. Then I will try other queries. Do I have to change candidates with mf2sn_rsform_submission_values????

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jatc_university_j32\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(77) : eval()'d code on line 47..........I used query $query = "SELECT FieldValue FROM mf2sn_rsform_submission_values WHERE SubmissionID IN( SELECT SubmissionID FROM mf2sn_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldValue LIKE'".$searchstring."' OR FieldValue LIKE '".$searchstring."'");

Comment: @user1997567 see my latest edit. And change the table candidates in the name of your table.

Comment: @user1997567 I had to basically create a pivot table which transposes the rows to columns. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/348fd9/39

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\jatc_university_j32\components\com_jumi\views\application\view.html.php(77) : eval()'d code on line 60

Comment: @user1997567 when something like this happens look at line 60. In this case the the ')' was not expected. Most likely a opening '(' was found but no end ')'. See, my edit.

Comment: @user1997567 I don't understand why you have decided not to accept my answer anymore. I'm very disappointed.